# How were there duplicate lines in package-lock.json?

Tags: node.js, heroku, npm

I ran into some trouble with deploying to heroku and later found out that my package-lock.json file had duplicate integrity values. I'm not too sure what package-lock.json does. Here is what it looked like:

[image]

I'm curious as to how this happened because I nor anyone else interacted with that file. I want to avoid this kind of obstacle in the future.

Edit: I forgot to mention that it seemed to be an error where the start script wasn't being read in package.json and I didn't have a procfile.

Comment: have you tried deleting package-lock.json and running `npm install` again? did the result change?

Comment: I fixed it by manually going through the file and deleting the duplicates myself. I'm not too keen on trying to repeat the problem again but I'll keep in mind reinstalling my package again if I ever run into this problem again and see if what you're suggesting works.

Comment: I’ve never seen this. I’m curious if you ever come up with repro steps.

Comment: if you are able to repro the problem, then it'd be wise to open an issue in npm github.